# cygwin cygdrive paths and Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cygwin, scp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cygwin cygdrive paths and Windows Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/291818/cygwin-cygdrive-paths-and-windows-command-prompt)

I'm having a weird issue with cygwin acting inconsistently between installations, specifically scp.  I have c:\cygwin\bin in my Windows PATH in both cases.  When I run the following command from a **Windows Command Prompt**, however, I get very different results between the two installations:

```
scp /cygdrive/c/something.txt User@server:${HOME}/something.txt
```

On the one machine it transfers the file just fine, but on the other machine I get an error:

```
/cygdrive/c/something.txt: No such file or directory
```

However, if I execute the command this way on the machine that gave me the error, it transfers just fine:

```
scp /c/something.txt User@server:${HOME}/something.txt
```

Why the differences?  Is there something I need to configure within cygwin to make this work with /cygdrive/c?

I've tried running `mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /cygdrive` but that doesn't fix the problem.

UPDATE: Here's something more interesting. If I do `ls /c` from a Windows command prompt I get what you would expect, as list of everything in C:.  However, `ls /cygdrive/c` says that it doesn't exist.  Running those commands from the cygwin bash yields exactly the opposite behavior.

Comment: Have you ruled out different (non-Cygwin) versions of `ls` and `scp`, which you don't see from inside bash because it comes from Cygwin and puts Cygwin `/bin` ahead of `PATH` on startup?

Comment: post this as an answer and I'll get you some rep.  This problem was fixed when I did `set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%` instead of `set PATH=%PATH$;C:\cygwin\bin.

Comment: You need to say @Gilles if you want someone to see a comment (unless it's attached to an answer or question of theirs).

Comment: Oops, may bad.  Thanks @Gilles.  If you post this as an answer I'll get you some rep. This problem was fixed when I did `set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%` instead of `set PATH=%PATH$;C:\cygwin\bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `scp` and `ls` commands are not Cygwin versions. Presumably, you start `bash`, your startup scripts change the `PATH` to put the Cygwin `/bin` in front, whereas otherwise your `PATH` has non-Cygwin versions of `scp` and `ls` early on.