# cygwin cygdrive paths and Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cygwin, scp

I'm having a weird issue with cygwin acting inconsistently between installations, specifically scp.  I have c:\cygwin\bin in my Windows PATH in both cases.  When I run the following command from a **Windows Command Prompt**, however, I get very different results between the two installations:

```
scp /cygdrive/c/something.txt User@server:${HOME}/something.txt
```

On the one machine it transfers the file just fine, but on the other machine I get an error:

```
/cygdrive/c/something.txt: No such file or directory
```

However, if I execute the command this way on the machine that gave me the error, it transfers just fine:

```
scp /c/something.txt User@server:${HOME}/something.txt
```

Why the differences?  Is there something I need to configure within cygwin to make this work with /cygdrive/c?

UPDATE: Here's something more interesting. If I do `ls /c` from a Windows command prompt I get what you would expect, as list of everything in C:.  However, `ls /cygdrive/c` says that it doesn't exist.  Running those commands from the cygwin bash yields exactly the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to do this is using the [mount](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#utils-cygdrive) command:

```
mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /c
```

or in your case, restore the default `/cygdrive` prefix...

Comment: Do you know if this is a default setting added in a newer version of cygwin?

Comment: it actually defaults to `/cygdrive` unless you manually change it (at least that's the way it was the last time I checked). You know there's nothing stopping you from having both (add an entry to /etc/fstab as explained in the documentation)

Comment: Hmm.  That's what's weird, this is a clean install of cygwin and I didn't change any of the options.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was my PATH precedence.  It was

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin
```

but it needed to be

```
PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%
```

After fixing the PATH `/cygdrive/c` resolved as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem after I installed Git, added it's bin to my PATH, then installed Cygwin and ran ssh-host-config to setup a Windows service for sshd. The problem seems to be that the way ssh-host-config registers the service causes sshd to invoke Git's bash (or scp, or ssh-provided command) executable rather than Cygwin's in the process of setting up an scp connection. To fix this, I removed the service as installed by ssh-host-config. From Cygwin bash, I executed `cygrunsrv -R sshd`. Then I re-registered the service with a PATH variable override,

```
cygrunsrv -I sshd -d "CYGWIN sshd" -p "/usr/sbin/sshd" \
  --env "PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:$PATH" \
  -a "-D" -u <priv_user> -w <password>
```

where priv_user is probably cyg_server. See http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-05/msg00012.html .